# Y intercept of pandas dataframe with multiple series for linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, statistics

```
count          716865                 716873                  716884                 716943  
0   -0.16029615828413712    -0.07630309240006158    0.11220663712532133    -0.2726775504078691  
1    -0.6687265363491811     -0.6135022705188075   -0.49097425130988914     -0.736020384028633  
2    0.06735205699309535     0.07948417451634422    0.09240256047258057     0.0617964313591086  
3      0.372935701728449     0.44324822316416074     0.5625073287879649     0.3199599294007491  
4    0.39439310866886124     0.45960496068147993     0.5591549439131621    0.34928093849248304  
5   -0.08007381002566456   -0.021313801077641505    0.11996141286735541   -0.15572679401876433
```

I have this dataframe named `df2_norm` on python. I compute slope with the following code:

```
    allowableCorr = self.df2_norm.corr(method = 'pearson') 
    
    self.slope = allowableCorr * (self.df2_norm.std().values / self.df2_norm.std().values[:, np.newaxis])
```

Q1) How do I compute the y intercept using pandas,numpy and matplotlib only into a matrix that is like a heat/correlation map?

Q2) Is there a way to compute the scatter plot for each column as the train data and the rest as the test data?

Thank you.